# Database engine that share a row among multiple tables

Tags: database-design, database-engine, virtual-columns

I'm wondering whether exists any database engine that can share cells or rows amongst many tables. For example:

```
TABLE Customer (
   CID: int
   Fullname: nvarchar(50)
   Age: int
)

TABLE Group (
   GID: int
   Name: nvarchar(50)
)

TABLE Customer_Group (
   CusName: nvarchar(50)
   GrpName: nvarchar(50)
)
```

In which, `Customer_Group` is designated for a certain query, like a column family in Cassandra. Now I want to insert to `Customer_Group` table a row whose `CusName` cell references to `Fullname` cell of a row in table `Customer`. Similar to `GrpName`.

As a result, when I update `Fullname` in `Customer` table, I don't have to update `Customer_Group` table, because it references to same cell address. And `Customer_Group` table itself doesn't have to store actual data for `CusName` but in fact is a pointer.

Does anyone know what database engine supports this idea? And is it a good idea though?

Comment: Why don't you store the IDs in the relation table instead of the name? You'd get the same effect, and that works "everywhere".

Comment: Is the question about Cassandra or a general one?

Comment: For Cassandra, read this nice article: [Cassandra Data Modeling Best Practices, Part 1](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/#.UzKvhvhoAQ8), especially the *"Example: Like relationship between User & Item"* which is similar to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Isn't this what CASCADE option on foreign key is supposed to do? You can find that in many DB engines.
2. It is not ok to perform the join on Fullname column as long as you have a CID column, which is supposed to be the identity. It is just a bad practice, and can have undesired effects - like the one you encountered.

In conclusion, either you change the joining column, or try to active the cascading on update capabilities of your DBMS.

Comment: I accept (1) as my answer. But about (2), I don't plan to do JOIN(s). I've been studying about designing data model in Cassandra (which doesn't support JOIN) and still wondering about how to deal with its data duplication (de-normalization). How didn't I think about CASCADE! (facepalm)

Comment: I didn't meant JOIN specifically as an operation, but more as a concept to logically link two tables. In other words, I believe that the Customer_Group table should be defined as Customer_Group (CID, GID).